# Custom colors for ls are correctly applied for some categories, but ignored for others

Tags: ls, colors, highlighting

With the help of `dircolors`, I changed `ls` colors. My `.dircolors` file is

```
FILE                   00;97
DIR                    00;96
LINK                   00;95
MULTIHARDLINK          00;34
ORPHAN                 91;01  # symlink to nonexistent file
MISSING                00;00 
EXEC                   91;00  # this is for files with execute permission
```

After `dircolors .dircolors >> .bashrc`, `ls` correctly colors its output
according to the definitions set, **except for the executable files**.
These are colored with the default terminal foreground color instead of red
(91;00). For example,

```
xterm -fg yellow # Executables become yellow on ls
xterm -fg green  # Executables become green on ls
```

and that is irrespective of the terminal (Xterm, Terminator, virtual console...).

I have also tried the dircolors file with only the `EXEC` line, producing the line

```
export LS_COLORS='ex=91;00:'
```

in my `.bashrc`, but still no color on executables.

What am I doing wrong in coloring the executable files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls` treats these settings as strings to send to the terminal. It doesn't know what they mean. It sends `ESC [ m`  *string* `;` to the terminal and it's up to the terminal to interpret this escape sequence.

The de facto standard for terminal escape sequences is [xterm](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html). In that document, `CSI` means `ESC [`, *Ps* is an integer and *Pm* is a semicolon-separated list of integers, so the relevant escape sequence is listed under [`CSI Pm m`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Pm-m.1CA7).

The terminal applies parameters in order. The parameter 0 resets all attributes including the color. So `91;00` is equivalent to `0`, use `91` instead (or `0;91` if you want to reset all attributes then set the foreground color). `91;01` is equivalent to `01;91` since the foreground color and the intensity are independent attributes.

`ls` normally starts off with the default attributes, and resets to the default attributes at the end of each colored name anyway, so `00;` in these settings is redundant.